# Animating CSS inside an image

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on an AI project that uses computer vision to detect a real coffee pot and how filled it is. I am trying to make a webpage with my very limited web dev experience to complement this. I want it to display what the computer vision is seeing in a "pretty" way by filling or draining a coffee pot image based on how full it is. The thing is, I'd also like to keep everything scaled and centered on the page correctly regardless of the size of the screen it is being viewed on(think mobile). I've got the centering and scaling down, but I cannot figure out how to keep those two features and have it animate the filling/draining. How would I mimic the liquid level but keeping the scaling?

Here is what I have so far:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #E0D9A8;
}
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#main {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#main .image1 {
  width: 31vw;
  min-width: 250px;
  min-height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
#main img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.circle:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background: white;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-bottom: 0vw;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="image1">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/DbBqGTp.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is a jsfiddle of that: https://jsfiddle.net/fuk291kf/3/

Answer (score 0):

Search for an image (or design with CSS) a cup with a simple form inside to fill it easily; then use Javascript to create the animation.

Here is an example. https://jsfiddle.net/nanilab/52jsfjjc/

`fill` variable has the percentage.